# Check if every element in array has a specfic value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with integers in it; and a function that returns a string. In this example, the function returns either `'solved'` or `'unsolved'`, based on the fact if a specific task was done before or not.

Now I need a way to call my function with every array element as parameter and check if the function returns `'solved'` for every element.

Small example with real values:

```
var array1 = [2,5,8]; // 2 is solved, 5 is solved, 8 is unsolved
var array2 = [2,5,6]; // every element is solved

if (Function returns solved for every element) {
// array2 would be accepted for this part
}
else {
// array1 would go in this branch
}
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` function?

Comment: May be `Array#every` is what you are looking for....

Comment: I don't get it.  Why is 8 not solved?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/L76r0st1/

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay because in another part of my programm i define if something is `solved`or `unsolved` if the user fills specific inputs with the correct values. In my example the input for task 8 didnt happen yet, therefor it is unsolved.

Comment: @Rayon i tried it with Array#every, but since i need to call a function and need to compare the return value of this function with a string, i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

If you already have a function that returns a string (*i.e.* `'solved'` or `'unsolved'`), then you can simply convert that to a boolean inside the callback you supply to `.every()`.

```js
var array1 = [2, 5, 8]; // 2 is solved, 5 is solved, 8 is unsolved
var array2 = [2, 5, 6]; // every element is solved

function isSolvedString(operand) {
  return operand < 8 ? 'solved' : 'unsolved';
}

function isSolved(current) {
  return isSolvedString(current) === 'solved' ? true : false;
}

console.log(array1.every(isSolved)); // false
console.log(array2.every(isSolved)); // true
```